# Can I safely steal from shops while invisible?

Tags: nethack

I'm currently in the middle of a game of Nethack, and have found a ring of invisibility. Also, I've come across a shop. I was wondering if the invisibility will let me steal items from the shop safely, or if the  shopkeeper will notice that his inventory is going missing. I'd rather not find out through experimentation, obviously.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, if you attempt to enter a shop while invisible, the shopkeeper will block the entrance with the message

> [name] detects your presence. "Invisible customers are not welcome!"

If you put on the ring while already inside the shop, the shopkeeper will refuse to move even if you pay for all of your items.

You can exploit this behavior to kill the shopkeeper if you have sufficient ranged weapons and [some](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Reflection) kind of [method](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Magic_resistance) to counter their [wand of striking](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wand_of_striking) and possibly [wand of magic missile](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wand_of_magic_missile) (note that reflection will not block the wand of striking!), but this will come with [murder penalities](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Murder) if you're not chaotic.

A character with intrinsic invisibility can still circumvent this by wearing a [mummy wrapping](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Mummy_wrapping), which will cancel the effects of the invisibility.

Comment: Can I destroy the door and enter the shop diagonally to get around the shopkeeper?

Comment: @Pavel No, invisibility has no effect in that case.

Comment: N.B. If you are intrinsically invisible, there's something you can wear that will make you visible again.

Comment: @Pavel If you destroy the door, the shopkeeper will be angry (and kill you) regardless of invisibility...

Comment: @zwol That's true, and probably something worth mentioning in the answer, thanks.

Comment: @Riker Not necessarily—you can still pay the shopkeeper the cost of the door to pacify them, which is likely less than the cost of the contents of the shop. But attempting to leave before the door repairs itself still angers the shopkeeper and summons Kops, invisible or not.

Comment: @Doorknob the door will be replaced anyway, so it doesn't actually gain you anything.